# cs50 pset5 unload problem - memory leakage

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to solve the cs50 pset5. I am using a tries method.

I can insert word into the tries successfully. However, when i unload the memory, it fails. I am so stuck at the unload problem for a few days.

When I try the unload function, it stated that Erorr Message: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000205d010 ***

It is probably due to my unload function, but i have drawn out the logic. It seems fine to me. Anyone has any idea where to amend?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LENGTH 45
#define SIZE_OF_CHILD 27

typedef struct Node {
    bool is_word;
    struct Node* child[SIZE_OF_CHILD];
} Node;


Node* root;
Node* temp;

Node* create_node(Node* node);
void test();
int cal_key(char c);
Node* insert(const char* word);
void unload(Node* node);

int main() {
    root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (root == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }

    root = create_node(root);
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (temp == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }

    test();

}

// **************** function to create a node *******************
Node* create_node(Node* node) {
    node->is_word = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_CHILD; i++) {
        node->child[i] = NULL;
    }
    return node; 
}

//************* calculate the key value ************
// Assume that the input is in lower case
int cal_key(char c) {
    if (isalpha(c)) {
        if (islower(c)) {
             return c - 'a';
        }
        else {
            return c + 32 -'a';
        }
    }
    else {
        return SIZE_OF_CHILD - 1;
    }
}

//*************** function to insert an item in the the node ***********
Node* insert(const char* word) {
    int str_len = strlen(word);
    temp = root;
    int key;
    for (int i = 0; i < str_len; i++) {
        key = cal_key(word[i]);
        if (temp->child[key] == NULL) {
            Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));  
            if (node == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in creating node\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            node = create_node(node);
            temp->child[key] = node;
        }

        temp = temp->child[key];
    }
    temp->is_word = true;
    return root;
}


//***************** function to unload a function ********************
void unload(Node* node) {
    // This is to find the last node
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_CHILD; i++) {
        if (node->child[i] != NULL) {
            unload(node->child[i]);
        }
    free(node);
    }
}

void test() {
    root = insert("Peter");
    unload(root);
    }
```

Comment: You are freeing `node` in a loop `SIZE_OF_CHILD` times.

Comment: OMG!! Thanks a lot! that solved my questions

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would like to have a follow up questions. The program can compile now. However, when i use valgrind, it said i did not free the memory of temp. When i try to put temp at the end of the main, it said double free or corruption (out). any advice what can i do?

Comment: you assign root to temp, so you have lost your reference to it and can't free it anymore, root and temp are aliases after your assignment and point to the same memory address. If you free them both, you will get a double free error.

Comment: if i will assign temp to root, does it mean that i dun needa malloc for the temp as temp is only a mirror of the root which is already malloc - ed. am i correct to think in this way?

Comment: Yes, but I can't decide for you if you need to allocate memory or not, only that you have created aliases, or a "mirror" as you call it.